# How would I replicate the intro of the linked video in manim?

Tags: manim

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVwxzDHniEw

I want to replicate the intro (Timestamp: 0:00 to 1:05) of the linked video in Manim. It doesn’t need to be exact; I just want the general flow of a curve gliding across the screen. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've left comments on what I'm doing.

```
from manim import *

class MovingScene(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        #create a value tracker to move a dot at the end of the graph
        k = ValueTracker(0)

        #make a graph
        axes = Axes(x_range=[0, 10, 1])
        
        #plot a sine wave on the graph
        graph = axes.plot(lambda x: np.sin(x))

        #make a dot that will move along the graph
        dot = always_redraw(
            lambda: Dot().move_to(
                    axes.c2p(k.get_value(), np.sin(k.get_value()))
            )
        )

        #add said dot to the scene, but not the graph so we don't see the axes
        self.add(dot)

        #add everything at once so that all of the actions happen at the same time
        self.play(MoveAlongPath(self.camera.frame, graph), Create(graph), k.animate.set_value(10),run_time = 10)
        self.wait()
```